# PowerBI: Counting days in a range on multiple line for staff absence purposes

Tags: powerbi

I'm working on a staff absence dashboard.

I'd like to know how many staff absences we have on a given day, based on the data below. I would like to be able to create a table of each day, which counts the number of absences on that day. The absence needs to count on the date, which could fall on the start date, end date or in between those.

```
Full Name   Start Date  End Date
----------------------------------
Employee D  03/11/2022  05/11/2022
Employee E  03/11/2022  04/11/2022
Employee A  04/11/2022  04/11/2022
Employee B  04/11/2022  06/11/2022
Employee C  04/11/2022  04/11/2022
Employee B  05/11/2022  06/11/2022
```

Based on the above table, I would expect the following:

```
Date       Count
----------------    
03/11/2022   2
04/11/2022   5
05/11/2022   3
06/11/2022   2
```

I use this formula but the end result isn't counting properly. Could someone help me with the formula?

```
Count per day = COUNTROWS(FILTER('Staff absence', 'Staff absence'[Absence Start Date]= MIN('Attendance Dates'[Date]) && 'Staff absence'[Absence End Date] >= MAX('Attendance Dates'[Date])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Best to fix this in your data model.  In Power Query join the Absences to the Date table, to create a table with one row for each employee for each day they are absent. Then you can simply count the rows in this table for a given day.

Here's an example:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45Wcs0tyMmvTE1VcFHSUTIw1jc01DcyMDICcUzhnFgdJIWuGApNsCt0RJUDc4yMoApjAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Full Name" = _t, #"Start Date" = _t, #"End Date" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Full Name", type text}, {"Start Date", type date}, {"End Date", type date}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Days", each List.Dates([Start Date], 1+Number.From([End Date]-[Start Date]), #duration(1, 0, 0, 0))),
    #"Expanded Days" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Days"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Days",{{"Days", "Day Absent"}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Start Date", "End Date"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I do this in PowerQuery?

Comment: Thanks for that @David Browne - Microsoft! The table doesn't look quite right yet, though, I only get absences for Employee D and E, and the date for E doesn't look right. I get 7/11/0200?

Comment: See update to answer.