# Membership retention matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am quite new to PBI and I am struggeling to make a matrix that shows retentioon of membership, month for month.

I have a member table with "valid from" and "valid to", I also have an "active" column (true/false).
I want the matrix to show months on the y-axis, 1-12 on the x-axis (number of months from the month I'm looking at on the y-axis), and each cell should show how many members have been lost since the previous month.
So the bottom line would show November and only one number, lost members so far in the month.
The line above that would show October and two numbers, lost members so far this month, and the loss in october, and so on.

Hope someone can help me out with this.

Thanks

I am not experienced enough with Dax to get it right.

Comment: Where's your sample data in text format?

Comment: I don't understand the question. It's my first posot on here, so if there is something I'm not doing correct, please help me out.

Comment: I suggest you transform this into a data model that has one row per member per month (or day).  See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74521206/powerbi-counting-days-in-a-range-on-multiple-line-for-staff-absence-purposes/74521418#74521418