# PowerBI Desktop - Historical record of Status Category

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I have a simplified PowerBI data model here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13aXUR8mw2MdP3tw9K9LHxhqRCZqPaLwz/view?usp=share_link

I want to make a timeseries visual that accounts for when a user's status category changes over time.

This is what the model looks like:
[image]

The current status table shows the status of users TODAY, and there is a separate table tracking the historical changes to their status. The visual so far looks like this:
[image]

I need a measure of some kind that will evaluate the correct count of users' status over time. Something like:
[image]

I have tried using LOOKUPVALUE, and different forms of CALCULATE but I haven't gotten very far.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: If you make HISTORY_STATUS have one row per user per day, this is trivial.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74521206/powerbi-counting-days-in-a-range-on-multiple-line-for-staff-absence-purposes/74521418#74521418

Comment: Thank you for your response. I decided to provide a simplified data model with hopes that I could find a methodology within a DAX abstraction. It isn't as feasible for me to complete this for the 'actual' model in PowerQuery.